# laravel lumen : how to upload an apk file of size 100 mb on digital ocean without presignedurl?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, digital-ocean, lumen

I am trying to upload an apk file of size about 80-100 megabyte on digital ocean using lumen . I have tried using pion/laravel-chunk-upload but I am not sure either lumen supports this package or not . So I am seeking for help . Thanks in Advance .